# Oracle creates type with compilation error

Tags: compiler-errors, object-oriented-database

i have a type created as follows:

```
create type age_t as object(
    dob DATE,
    member function age_f return number);
    /
```

to define the body i wrote the following code:

```
create or replace type body age_t as(
        member function age_f return number is
        v_dob date;
        age number(3);
        v_dob := to_date(dob);
        begin
        age := trunc(months_between(sysdate,v_dob))/12;
        return age;
        end;
        end;
         );
        /
```

Oracle gives me compiled with error message.
Please tell me where the problem is.
I am using oracle 11g sql client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the create body type definition, remove the brackets "()" that are after "CREATE OR REPLACE BODY age_t AS" statement and before "/".
Also, take the v_dob := to_date(dob) statement into begin and end section, or initialize v_dob during creation. That is v_dob date := to_date(dob);

Correct code without compilation errors;

```
   `create or replace type body age_t as
    member function age_f return number is
    v_dob date := to_date(dob);
    age number(3);
    begin
    age := trunc(months_between(sysdate,v_dob))/12;
    return age;
    end;
    end;
    /`
```

You may find more here [www.exploredatabase.com](http://exploredatabase.com)